# Build data.frame to set names?

Tags: r

I can convert list into data.frame with do.call function:

```
z=list(c(1:3),c(5:7),c(7:9))
x=as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,z))
names(x)=c("one","two","three")
x

##   one two three
## 1   1   2     3
## 2   5   6     7
## 3   7   8     9
```

I want to make it to be more concise ,merge  the two statement into one statment,can i?

```
x=as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,z))  
names(x)=c("one","two","three")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is the `structure()` function, this is in base, and more general:

```
structure(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,z)), names=c('a','b','c'))
```

Answer (score 7):

`setNames` is what you want. It is in the `stats` package which should load with `R`

`setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,z)), c('a','b','c'))`

```
##   a b c
## 1 1 2 3
## 2 5 6 7
## 3 7 8 9
```